# Handling Asp.net Errors C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project I have a custom error solution. In the controller I do a try/catch and handle the exception with a popup instead of using the forms method. I can handle all of the errors correctly that are specified in the Model as the error, however I am unable to get a proper error coming from a `AddError` result. This is what I use:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
```

And then I put `return content(sb.ToString());`
This will either show that it was successful or not. If there is an error I use this:

```
     foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
     {
       foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
       {
           sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
       }
     }
```

And of course the Exception of the try/catch would be:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
 }
```

My question is how do I implement the `AddErrors` from context to this. I have tried
`sb.Append(result);` and `sb.Append(result.Errors);` I only see the actual error in my locals window under Error. I would like them to show up in the popup.
By the way this is for a registration form. The registration form normally just has `AddErrors(result);`

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Added AddErrors

```
  private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us part of `AddErrors` code? thanks

Comment: @D-Shih Added it above.

Comment: Have you tried `ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `result` is a type of `IdentityResult` but `StringBuilder.Append` might need to pass string value in that, so if we want to use `StringBuilder.Append` to append information that needs to convert as a string.

one way we can try to let `result` object deserialize as a JSON string value.

We can use [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) which is created by [`Json.NET`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

```
StringBuilder.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Errors));
```